# Rviz error skipping XML document

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every time I load Rviz, I see exactly four of these errors in my console:

```
[ERROR] [1430107225.314958023]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz_backdrop/plugin_description.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
```

No file called /opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz_backdrop/plugin_description.xml seems to exist, even though I have all the ros-indigo-rviz-* packages installed.

Is this anything I should be concerned about? How do I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207967/rviz-error-skipping-xml-document/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> No file called `/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz_backdrop/plugin_description.xml` seems to exist, [..]

And that I think is the problem.

The error message is slightly confusing - but logical - in this case: internally, the XML document is empty (as it doesn't exist), causing the parser to assume it's malformed (as *no elements* includes *no root element*).

You don't mention it, but if you installed `rviz_backdrop` (part of `pr2_hack_the_future`) from debs, then looking at the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_hack_the_future/blob/79f98d6df4661a0842f4ee39f9cb6cade8444002/rviz_backdrop/CMakeLists.txt) it seems the `rviz_backdrop` package doesn't correctly install all its non-executable assets (ie: there is no `install` target for the `plugin_description.xml` file).

If you didn't install from debs, but ran `catkin_make install` on the workspace containing the `pr2_hack_the_future` packages, the result would be the same.

If you don't need the `rviz_backdrop` plugin, you can ignore this warning (the plugin will just not be found).

In any case, reporting this to the [pr2_hack_the_future/issues](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_hack_the_future/issues) tracker would be the best thing to do, so the maintainer can fix the build script.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-04-27**:
I did install everything from deb, including rviz_backdrop, but still get the error. How do I install the media? Shouldn't that have been included in the deb?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-27**:\

> How do I install the media?

This is just a single xml file, no 'media' involved. Either copy the `plugin_description.xml` to the `share/rviz_desktop` directory by hand for now, or build everything from source. In any case, log an issue with the maintainers.